VARIANT and PngImage
I have an image of a signature, which is stored in a variable of a type VARIANT. How can I convert this VARIANT variable and assign it to the TPngImage? Tried different kinds of conversion, assigning to TPngImage, without success,... I'm using C++Builder 10.4.2
Thanks
